# Extract entry within </h3> HTML tag - Python

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am working on a webscraping project with employment listings data. I am having some trouble working out the best way to extract content from within html tags. Code below output the following:

<< h3 class="job-title heading-large -no-margin-bottom">Remediation Data Analyst /h3>>

I simply need to strip away the html such that the output is simply "Remediation Data Analyst". I know this is a simple one.

Script:

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

url = requests.get('https://au.jora.com/j?sp=homepage&q=analytics&l=Sydney+NSW')
soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content, 'html.parser')

containers = soup.find_all(class_='job-item')

for c in containers:
    try:
        print(c.find_all(class_='job-title'))
    except:
        print('n/a')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search for the h3 tag with the relevant properties (class in your case).

```
soup.find_all("h3", {"class": 'job-item'})

# To access the text inside the tag you simply use the .text attribute
soup.find_all("h3", {"class": 'job-item'}).text
```

In the case above it probably wouldn't work directly as the `find_all` would return a list of items but you could iterate through the items and use `.text` to get the text inside the tag.

Comment: yes Grizzle, I found that this my approach using find_all was the issue. Given that each container only contains one entry for each job listing (ie. Title, salary etc), find is sufficient. This then allows me to pass in .text [Thank you for looking at this for me :)]

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it simply by using `find()` rather than `find_all()` and calling the `.text` method.

```
for c in containers:
    try:
        c1 = c.find(class_='job-title').text
        print(c1)
    except:
        print('n/a')
```

output:

```
Remediation Data Analyst
Data & Analytics Manager
Head of Data & Analytics
Senior Manager, Data Science Australia
Senior Associate, Data & Analytics
Head of Analytics
Reporting Analyst
Head of Data & Analytics
Senior Manager- Data & Analytics
Analytics Manager
```